# Read from standard input several times in Java

Tags: java, stdin

I've been struggling with this for a while now, though I thought it would be really simple haha.

A little background info: I'm making a small program to answer a web survey automatically (using Selenium WebDriver). Each survey is completed under a user and password. My goal is that my program asks me the questions with their id (like ID1: ___, ID2: ____, etc), and do that for each user+pass.

I created a method to get the users and passwords from a textfile and save them into a List of String[2].

```
    // Just a test list with the name (or id) of each question
    List<String> nombrePreguntas = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("nombre1", "nombre2", "nombre3", "nombre4"));

    // read users from file -> usuarios[0] = user, usuarios[1] = pass.
    List<String[]> usuarios = leerUsuarios("entrada.txt");

    for (String[] u : usuarios) {
        // print each user and pass
        System.out.println(u[0] + " - " + u[1]);
        // for each user+pass, read the questions and ask for their answer in stdin
        List<Integer> respuestas = leerRespuesta(nombrePreguntas);
        System.out.println(respuestas );
    }
```

That works only ONCE, for the first user. The program asks for the answer of the 4 questions and then print out the answers. After that, it just prints the user+pass with the name of every question and an empty array of answers, like this:

```
usuario1 - pass1
nombre1: 1
nombre2: 2
nombre3: 3
nombre4: 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
usuario2 - pass2
nombre1: nombre2: nombre3: nombre4: []
usuario3 - pass3
nombre1: nombre2: nombre3: nombre4: []
```

I don't know what's the best way to do what I want to do. If you can't find a solution for this, I would also appreciate some advice on alternative methods to get the answers for every user+pass from the standard input.

This is the function that reads from the stdin:

```
public static List<Integer> leerRespuesta(List<String> nombrePreguntas) {
    List<Integer> respuestas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Para cada pregunta, habrá una respuesta
    boolean licencia = true;
    for (String np : nombrePreguntas) {
        // just a feature that I must implement
        if(licencia == false && (np.equals("LM2") || np.equals("LM3") || np.equals("LM4"))) {
            continue;
        }

        // Print the name/id of the question
        System.out.print(np + ": ");

        if(in.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = in.nextLine();

            while(!StringUtils.isNumeric(s)) {
                System.out.println("It must be a number.");
                System.out.print(np + ": ");
                if(in.hasNextLine())
                    s = in.nextLine();
            }

            if(np.equals("LM1") && s.equals("1"))
                licencia = false;

            respuestas.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }
    }
    in.close();
    return respuestas;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to stack the survey results?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean (english is not my main language). But here's what I want to do: I want to answer a lot of surveys in a row, and save their answers in a list or a text file so after that I can execute a method that asks for a user, pass and a list of answers and apply that to every user+pass and answers I read.

Comment: A survey is designed to get information (or opinions) from a person; i.e. a real human being.  Jim is asking **why** you are writing a program to answer the survey lots of times?

Comment: Oh, because I already have the surveys answered physically, I just need to enter the result in a web platform and it's too tedious to do it manually. I mean, I will have to do it manually anyway, but I'd rather do them all at once and in a simple program, not the whole web form, press okay, login, etc. thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read standard input lots of times.  Java does not support this<sup>1</sup>.

What you *could* do is read standard input once and capture it all as a `String`.  Then *repeatedly* create and use a `StringReader` or `Scanner` from the `String`.

---

<sup>1 .... because typical operating systems don't support it.</sup>

Comment: Oh, so I'm kinda screwed huh. Alright, I will try that, but how would you advice me to separate the answers? I mean, there are 140 questions per survey... how can I know when one finishes and the other one starts, and 'assign' them to different users?
Thanks.